# Spring boot app endpoints with Azure App service

Tags: java, spring, azure, spring-boot

I'm trying to deploy simple Spring Boot app to Azure App Service, but looks like app doesn't starts.

My app has on rest endpoint

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
}
```

I tried to deploy using azure-webapp-maven-plugin, config in pom looks like this

```
  <plugin>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <schemaVersion>V2</schemaVersion>

                <!-- Web App information -->
                <resourceGroup>${resourceGroup}</resourceGroup>
                <appName>boot-test-app</appName>
                <region>westeurope</region>
                <pricingTier>P1V2</pricingTier>
                <runtime>
                    <os>linux</os>
                    <javaVersion>jre8</javaVersion>
                    <webContainer>tomcat 8.5</webContainer>
                </runtime>
                <appSettings>
                    <property>
                         <name>PORT</name>
                        <value>80</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>JAVA_OPTS</name>
                        <value>-Xmx512m -Xms512m</value>
                    </property>
                </appSettings>
                <deployment>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
                            <!--<targetPath>/home/site/wwwroot/webapps/ROOT/</targetPath>-->
                            <includes>
                                <include>*.war</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </deployment>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Plugin says deploy was successful, but when i'm opening app webpage - i got 404 error.
The same if I'm deploying using Azure Plugin for Intellij Idea.

What i'm missing? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this tutorial to deploy:[Spring Boot on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/spring-framework/deploy-spring-boot-java-app-with-maven-plugin?view=azure-java-stable). I test multiple times, this works for. Or you could just use my pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
  <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>  
  <version>0.1.0</version>  
  <parent> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>  
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version> 
  </parent>  
  <dependencies> 
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
    </dependency>  
    <!-- tag::actuator[] -->  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId> 
    </dependency>  
    <!-- end::actuator[] -->  
    <!-- tag::tests[] -->  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>  
      <scope>test</scope> 
    </dependency>  
    <!-- end::tests[] --> 
  </dependencies>  
  <properties> 
    <java.version>1.8</java.version> 
  </properties>  
  <build> 
    <plugins> 
      <plugin> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
      </plugin>  
      <plugin> 
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>  
        <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
        <version>1.6.0</version>  
        <configuration>
          <schemaVersion>V2</schemaVersion>
          <resourceGroup>group name</resourceGroup>
          <appName>app name</appName>
          <region>westeurope</region>
          <pricingTier>P1V2</pricingTier>


          <!-- Begin of App Settings  -->
          <appSettings>
             <property>
                   <name>JAVA_OPTS</name>
                   <value>-Dserver.port=80</value>
             </property>
          </appSettings>

          <runtime>
            <os>linux</os>
            <javaVersion>jre8</javaVersion>
            <webContainer>jre8</webContainer>
          </runtime>
          <deployment>
            <resources>
              <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
                <includes>
                  <include>*.jar</include>
                </includes>
              </resource>
            </resources>
          </deployment>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>  
      <plugin> 
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>  
        <executions> 
          <execution> 
            <goals> 
              <goal>integration-test</goal>  
              <goal>verify</goal> 
            </goals> 
          </execution> 
        </executions> 
      </plugin> 
    </plugins> 
  </build> 
</project>
```

After deployment, if the web still don't show right page, check the runtime stack if it's same as you defined in the pom.xml.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to remove `<webContainer>` option.